# Can we use variable in name of variable in python

Tags: python

I am trying to create a variable in python with prefix as `list` and then number which will be generated dynamically in the script. For example

I am trying to have a list10 where list is the prefix and 10 is the number generated dynamically.

In TCL we give like

```
list${i}
```

Is there same way in python too?

Comment: Use a `list`! `mylist.append(myvalue)`

Comment: Yes, the way to do this in Python and Tcl is not to use sequential variable names. It is a terrible practice since it turns data into code. Yes, tcl allows you to do it, but `dict set mydict $i  [list 4 5 6]` is far better as are the Python answers below.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The pythonic way to do this would be to make a dictionary to store your lists with the generated names as the dictionary's keys:

```
d = {}
d['list1'] = [1, 2, 3]
d['list2'] = ['a', 'b', 'c']
```

EDIT: generate key names

You can create keys like this:

```
key = 'list' + str(1)  # or whatever number you are using
d[key] = [your list]
```

END EDIT

Or if you don't really need to know the names, store your lists in a list and retrieve them by index:

`lists = [[1, 2, 3], ['a', 'b', 'c']]`

Comment: How to get list1, list2 etc as 1 and 2 are also made dynamically in the script.

Comment: @Nitesh `'list' + str(1)`...!? Or, again, simply a *list*, which takes care of indices itself?!

Comment: I think it is not solving purpose. Can I append in dict keys. Say I have declared dict key as dict[key1]. I want to append in this. I am trying as dict[key1].append = value. But it is givng error

Comment: Please open a new question explaining what you really want to do and showing your code - the question that you asked has been answered.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `locals()`, `vars()`, or `globals()` and inject your variable name there. For eg.

```
>>> list10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'list10' is not defined
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, '__package__': None, 'x': [], '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> locals()['list10'] = []
>>> locals()
{'__builtins__': <module '__builtin__' (built-in)>, 'list10': [], '__package__': None, 'x': [], '__name__': '__main__', '__doc__': None}
>>> list10
[]
```

Generally, if you're doing something like this, you'd probably be better off with using a dictionary to store the variable name and the value(s).

For eg.

```
>>> my_lists = {}
>>> my_lists['list10'] = []
```

And then when you want to look it up, you can `.get()` it if you want robustness against a variable name not existing, or directly accessing it if you're going to guard against non-existence yourself.

```
>>> the_list_i_want = my_lists.get('list10')
>>> the_list_i_want = my_lists['list10']  # Will raise a KeyError if it does not exist
```

Comment: Using [`locals()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#locals) for this is specifically warned against in the documentation.